# BackgroundWorker doesn't work

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

So this is the code:

```
void scrape() 
{ 
    int i = 1;
    ......
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    i = i+1;
}
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    scrape();
}
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The problem is that if i click botton1 nothing happens, if I just use scrape() on button1onclick it work just fine. Why the background worker don't execute scrape and making the progress bar work?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you assign those event handler functions to their events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Initialization / Constructor of the program you need to add these lines to make it work

```
BackgroundWorker1.DoWork += new BackgroundWorkerDoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorker1DoWork)
```

same way it goes to other part of the code as well

```
BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler (backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Comment: I don't understand why but i got "The name 'BackgroundWorker1DoWork' does not exist in the current context"  I'm using them incorectly?

Comment: Just Change it to BackgroundWorker1_DoWork

Comment: already did notice but still dont' scrape :\
edit: I used them in public form() right?

Comment: You can have a look on [CodeProject for Background Worker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners) .... its almost the same code which you might be looking for.

Comment: I already read that but I0m starting thinking that the problem is the scrape even if it work alone...

Comment: confirmed it's scrape the problem :\

Answer (score 0):

In your `scrape()` method how do you utilize the variable `i`? For it to work `i` should be incremented via loop as shown below:

```
void scrape()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the above code works for me. And then do not forget to wire the events and properties that are required:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true; //Report a progress
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += BackgroundWorker1DoWork; //The scrape
```

Define this:

```
void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    scrape();
}
```

Comment: same as above, I don't understand why but i got "The name 'BackgroundWorker1DoWork' does not exist in the current context"
I'm using them incorectly?

Comment: See the edit above, you need to define `BackgroundWorker1DoWork` in your application.

Comment: If it helps, consider downloading this application (dev using VS2013): https://www.dropbox.com/s/30hbnmfbas3dx6i/WindowsFormsApplication5.zip?dl=0 (Try to check for differences in your code)

Comment: I already did as in first post
void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    scrape();
}